# Open and edit in google drive from my php-application

Tags: php, google-docs, google-drive-api

users can upload files from my php-application which are to be stored in my google drive. users need to view those documents and are able to update the files.how can i make this possible.i am new to google apis.please help me. thanks in advance for any answers

Comment: There're samples for uploading and downloading files to/from GDrive, on https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: you could also make a shared folder in the drive area and make that shared, i believe this should make any files inserted into the folder the same permission...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the users editor permissions on those files. Look at the [permissions.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) method of the Drive API. You will create a permission for every user who need to be able to edit the file, and then they can edit it in Google Drive.